# ListView scrolling UI glitch

Tags: android, listview, picasso

I have a listView that has an odd visual glitch when scrolling:

[image: during scroll]

After scrolling:

[image: after scroll]

This happens intermittently and I don't have a good way to reproduce this other than close my app and start scrolling the list. Any ideas on what is going on?

Here is some (maybe) relevant code from my arrayAdapter I use for this listView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.event,
                parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventDate);
        holder.attending = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventAttending);
        holder.bgImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsImg);
        holder.gpsIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconGPS);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Configure the view for this event
    final Event event = getItem(position);
    holder.gpsIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Util.openMap(getContext(), event.getAddress());
        }
    });
    holder.name.setText(event.getName());
    holder.date.setText(Util.convertDashesToDate(event.getDate()));
    holder.attending.setText(event.getAttending());
    RequestUtil.getImageFullUrl(getContext(), event.getImage_url(), holder.bgImg, 10, 0);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Event getItem(int position) {
    return new Event(events.get(position));
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView date;
    TextView attending;
    ImageView bgImg;
    ImageView gpsIcon;
}
```

Picasso code for getting the image:

```
public static void getImageFullUrl(final Context context, String url, ImageView imgView, int radius, int margin) {
    instance = appSingleton.getInstance(context);
    instance.getPicasso()
            .load(url)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .tag("Request")
            .transform(new RoundedTransformation((int) Util.convertPixelsToDp(radius, context),
                    (int) Util.convertPixelsToDp(margin, context))) // TODO Reuse RoundedTransform
            .into(imgView);
}
```

Comment: getter should not create objects.

Comment: Why? This prevents a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your code that sets the image:

```
 RequestUtil.getImageFullUrl(getContext(), event.getImage_url(), holder.bgImg, 10, 0);
```

is loading (downloading) the image on the UI thread, causing blocking of the thread.

I don't know what's behind your RequestUtil, but I'd suggest using one of the several good image loading libraries for Android, such as Picasso. Picasso, for example, will handle loading the image on a background thread for you.